# Searching apt list n* returns nothing

Tags: regex, apt

I am unsure if this is just a regex quirk that I have forgotten but here goes. I was trying to find the nvidia-docker2 apt and found that the following search returns nothing other than 'Listing... Done.'

```
sudo apt list nvidia-*
```

Even searching n* returns nothing. All other searches work fine; a*, b* etc. In fact N* (capital N) lists all the n* apts it's just all searches starting with 'n' that return nothing.

Whats going on?

edit: further investigation finds all searches up till 'nvidia-docker2' returns nothing (only if all lowercase). e.g. 'nvidia-d*' and 'nvidia-do*' returns nothing but 'nvidia-dr*' lists the nvidia-drivers.

Comment: Do you have a file with name starting with `n` in the current directory? Please enclose wildchars in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your shell expands nvidia-* using filenames in your current directory.

You can try `echo nvidia-*` to realize this.

So for example if you have a `nvidia-xyz.tar` in your current directory `apt list nvidia-*` will actually execute `apt list nvidia-xyz.tar`

You can use quotes in order to prevent the shell from expanding your pattern:

```bsh
apt list "nvidia-*"
```